# How to block sending mail from domain in postfix?

Tags: postfix

How to block sending mail from domain?

I tried

```
main.cf  
    smtpd_sender_access = hash:/etc/postfix/access

access  
    blabla.com REJECT
```

But when i send mail from blabla.com to somedomain, it still sends the mail.

Comment: Could you post some more information? Where does the mail come from?

Comment: I use easySCP open source hosting management system. One domain was hacked through Joomla and sending out spam mail. So I need to block all outgoing mails from this domain.

Comment: if that domain is still hacked, you should fight the root cause and disable that domain completely. it will be hacked again quite fast.

Comment: use postfwd, homepage here: http://postfwd.org/ configuration example here:
https://www.nooblet.org/blog/2010/postfwd-example-configuration/

Answer (score 3):

I think that you don't have the problem with domain... It can only be the email account (or several accounts). 
Change passwords for all compromised accounts, use Policyd to limit number of messages which any user can send and before anything, apply the fix to close the security hole which is used to compromise the account(s)

If you still want to blacklist domain, try the next

Create new file with

> nano /etc/postfix/rbl_blacklist

Add domain

domain.com REJECT

Save file, exec

> postmap /etc/postfix/rbl_blacklist

Find the

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions

line and add

> check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_blacklist

into it.

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access
>   hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_blacklist

If you have several other directives, move this one to the top and restart Postfix. Remmember that if your site is hacked, this won't help.

Comment: So has anyone had success with this method?  I have not been able to block a domain sender from sending - and see them sending via the logs.  Just wondered if there's an updated way?

Comment: This method worked for me. But you can find more precise instructions here: https://nacko.net/postfix-block-specific-from-specific-domains-centos-6-rhel-6/